# Why does this code leak memory? (Out arguments and pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

i'm new to C++. i wrote this method to poll an accelerometer. it gets called repeatedly, and leaks memory.

```
AccelSample SensorObj::GetReport() {
    ISensorDataReport* pReport;
    HRESULT hr = pSensor->GetData(&pReport);

    // theoretically, i would fill this struct with the values from pReport, but this is just here for testing.
    AccelSample sample;
    sample.x = 0;
    sample.y = 0;
    sample.z = 0;
    sample.timestamp = 0;

    return sample;
}
```

the line

```
HRESULT hr = pSensor->GetData(&pReport);
```

seems to be the source of leak. if i comment it out, there's no leak. the definition of GetData is

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetData(__RPC__deref_out_opt ISensorDataReport **ppDataReport) = 0;
```

the documentation for this API shows GetData being called the same way.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

if i understand it right, GetData takes an out argument that is a pointer to a pointer. by passing &pReport to it, i'm passing the "address of" the pointer pReport. is that right? shouldn't this be ok?

EDIT: i should have mentioned that i tried "delete pReport". i get an error that says something like "Debug assertion failed. _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse".

Comment: You never do `delete pReport`.

Comment: @Barmar that depends how `pSensor::GetData` is implemented.

Comment: @Quirliom The fact that he's leaking memory implies that it allocates a new object.

Comment: While the example usage never tries to free an ISensorDataReport, it *does* show several calls to PropVariantClear to free the results of GetSensorValue. Do you do anything with pReport in your actual code, such as calling GetSensorValue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code violates COM’s ref counting mechanism and works fine when you have only one reference to the object:

```
delete pReport
```

In general, you should to call Release method or use CComPtr smart pointer:

```
CComPtr<ISensorDataReport> pReport;
HRESULT hr = pSensor->GetData(&pReport);
```

Comment: i get an error if i call delete pReport, but using a smart pointer worked. thanks.